# Whether this sentence is grammatically and semantically correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, spoken-english, semantics

Indian constitution is not as flexible and rigid as British constitution and American constitution respectively.

Comment: Hello Ritesh. A post "Is it correct" doesn't show why you think there is a problem. As we don't know why you are asking this or what you have already done we can't answer the question.

Comment: Could do with some definite articles.

Comment: There is no need for the word _respectively_.

Comment: No need for 'constitution' to appear more than once.

Comment: @KateBunting Here "respectively" means "not as flexible as the British constitution and not as rigid as the American constitution". It's hard to imagine something being flexible and rigid at the same time since they are antonyms.

Comment: @CJDennis Silly me, I should have spotted that!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I think the word "constitution" should not be repeated again. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It must be like this:  “The Indian constitution....” And “the British and American constitutions respectively”.

Comment: Why "must" it be like that? This is an opportunity to teach, but you're not teaching anything here.